# Displaying a count of certain text on a Card visual in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am creating a report in Power BI, which is fetching data from an Excel Sheet. In that Excel sheet one of the columns is the "Status" which is either "Completed", "Not Started" or a percentage as shown below:

[image: Excel Column]

What I actually want to do is to have a card visual in Power BI which shows the count of completed and not started depending on the filter i am using on top which are date and some other parameters.

When I use a card and click on add quick measure I do not see an option to make my own query. Or am i missing something or doing wrong?

Any help on this would be really appreciated.

[image: Options in New quick measure]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the ribbon, click New Measure. Do you not see that option?

[image]

Comment: Oh yes I see that option, sorry I missed that one!